# JavaFX Simplest way to get cell data using table index

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there any simplest way to get cell data of a tableview in javafx using table index values  without using cellfactory function.Iam looking simple single line code like this

```
  getValueAt(1,2);//1=column number 2=row number
```

So i can access the cell data on column=1 and row=2.Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite sure what you are attempting to do here?  Can you provide a little more context?  Since the cells are reused you don't access the data based on the cell.  However you can get to data based on the row in the backing collection.

Comment: @purning pigeon.Here i would like to set background color for a cell using index values of table.Cell factory function is not aaplicable on my table bcause here i have more than 40 columns.So i prefer this way like what we do in java swing jtable.

Comment: You can set the color in the cellFactory of the column during the update item and apply the css there.  If not, when you scroll the table, your colors will not change.

Comment: @purning pigeon.Here actually iam displaying an attendence report of a year in tableview.i would like to indicate background color for Presented and Absent  days on cells.So background color is not fixed one it may be changed.

Comment: So as per my knowledge i knew that we can use cellfactory function for a particular row or coloumn.But its diificult for me bcoz i have 40 plus columns

Comment: Is your entire row going to change color based on the attendance?  If so you could look at rowfactory

Comment: But row factory also using the same method like column factory. Data are retrieving using get and set methods.

Comment: Can you provide code as to what you have tried and what is not working so that I can see if I can provide you a simpler answer?  Using cellfactory is usually the way you handle the cell rendering.  If you can change the css on an entire row, then you can use the row factory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the observable using the `TableColumn` and use `getValue` on it:

```
public static Object getValueAt(TableView table, int column, int row) {
    return table.getColumns().get(column).getCellObservableValue(row).getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort,But how i can link it with my table

Comment: @AmeenAmi By passing said table as first parameter to the method, if by "link" you mean "use with". Or extend `TableView`, remove static and the first parameter and replace `table` with `this`, if it absolutely needs to be a instance method for the table... There simply is no method in `TableView` that does this for you.

Comment: oh my god.I have implemented your code like this, String a=personTable.getColumns().get(0).getCellObservableValue(0).getValue().toString();
             System.out.println("value"+a);,and i got desired output.Thankyou so much

Comment: And i have one or more question to you.Like this how i can set background color for a cell using index value.

Comment: @You need to store the data somewhere else and use a custom `cellFactory` to adjust the look of the cells. Note that there may not be a `Cell` for an item at a given time and `Cell`s are reused for different items, which is why something like this is necessary.

Comment: You *can* get the data this way, but if you're doing this, it's pretty much a sign that something is designed wrong. The `TableColumn` returned by `table.getColumns().get(...)` is part of the *view*, so you are effectively retrieving the data from the view, and that is basically always an error. You should get the data from the model.

Comment: How about when you add a filter to the tableView? How can you get only the visible data from the tableView?

Comment: @GherbiHicham This is unrelated to the question or the answer. Please ask a question or post a comment at a question/answer that is actually related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code. when you select a row using mouse

```
ProcessDetail pd =
 (ProcessDetail)tableDefined.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println("Value is in this row which is selected"+pd.getStatus());
```