# Get the location of a tableview cell in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

new to JavaFX, and been trying to get a TableView cell's position by row, col indices. Looking for something like Swing's `JTable.getCellRect;`

I've seen solutions for the case where a specific cell's value is needed,
([JavaFX Simplest way to get cell data using table index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104798/javafx-simplest-way-to-get-cell-data-using-table-index))

I've also figured it would be enough to get the `TableCell` of the corresponding row and column, then get bounds and use `localToScreen` etc, but couldn't find a way to get a specific `table-cell` as well.

Would love any help with any of that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no real way to do this in JavaFX (at least, not without a considerable amount of hacking). The issue is that cells are only created for *visible* data, and are reused, e.g. as the user scrolls. So cells may not even exist for some rows and columns. There is almost certainly an easier way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do - why do you think you need this location?

Comment: I'm actually converting an old GUI written using Swing to JavaFX.
Just thought it would make my job easier :) - and pretty weird they didn't add that functionality to FX.

Comment: That doesn't really explain what you're trying to do though. These are different toolkits, and they work in different ways, so you will have to approach some things differently. There's no direct way to do what you're asking for, so you'll need a different approach for it. You can basically access cells either via the cell factory (which enables you to write code that is executed when the cell is created, or reused), or via a lookup. Either of those will get very ugly, very quickly, for what you are asking to do.

Comment: Yeah I know. I still didn't figure out the original usage of the location as there's lack of documentation. I thought it would save me some work just translating the same functionality.

How would the lookup approach look?

Comment: It's not weird at all - at least not to me. Once you realize cells are not in a 1-1 relationship with the data, or even consistently displaying data from the same location in the data index, it doesn't really make sense to access a cell directly.

Comment: Added an answer, with a [demo](https://gist.github.com/james-d/85233c1fb6343c5f7df69257322ff8f7) if you really want to do this. (But again, it's likely not what you really should be doing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this in JavaFX, by design. Since cells are only created for data that is currently visible, and are reused (for example as the user scrolls around the table), there isn't a 1-1, or even a consistent, relationship between any given cell and the "location" in the table's backing data. Consequently, you really should not even attempt to find a cell for a given data item, and should try to find another approach to whatever you are trying to do.

(From a MVC design approach, this makes sense too: you are asking to find the *view* (cell) from the model (data); the model is supposed to be completely unaware of the view.)

If you really want to attempt this (and, in case it's not clear, I think you should find another approach), you can try to keep track of the cells for each position as they change, using something like the following:

```
TableView<SomeDataType> table = new TableView<>();

Map<TableColumn<SomeDataType, ?>, Map<Number, TableCell<SomeDataType, ?>>> cells = new HashMap<>();

TableColumn<SomeDataType, SomeColumnDataType> column = new TableColumn<>(...);
cells.put(column, new HashMap<>();

column.setCellValueFactory(...);

column.setCellFactory(tc -> {
    TableCell<SomeDataType, SomeColumnDataType> cell = new TableCell<SomeDataType, SomeColumnDataType>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(SomeColumnDataType item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    cell.indexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
        if (oldIndex != null) {
            cells.get(column).remove(oldIndex);
        }
        if (newIndex != null && newIndex.intValue() != -1) {
            cells.get(column).put(newIndex, cell);
        }
    });

    return cell ;
});

// repeat for other columns...
```

Then you can do

```
TableCell<SomeDataType, ?> cell = cells.get(someColumn).get(someIndex);
```

to get a cell for a specific column and row index. Note that you need to check for null (if that data doesn't currently have a cell).

This will probably need very careful debugging, but the approach should work.

**Update:** I made an SSCCE using this technique [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/85233c1fb6343c5f7df69257322ff8f7).

You could also try via a lookup. Lookups are not very robust, and won't work at all until CSS has been applied to the scene graph, but you can try something like this:

```
TableColumn<...> columnOfInterest = ... ;
int rowIndexOfInterest = ... ;

TableCell<?, ?> cell = null ;
for (Node n : table.lookupAll(".table-cell")) {
    TableCell<?,?> c = (TableCell<?,?>) n ;
    if (c.getTableColumn() == columnOfInterest 
            && c.getIndex() == rowIndexOfInterest) {
        cell = c ;
        break ;
    }
}

if (cell != null) {
    // ...
}
```

or in a more Java 8 approach:

```
table.lookupAll(".table-cell").stream()
    .map(TableCell.class::cast)
    .filter(c -> c.getTableColumn() == columnOfInterest && c.getIndex() == rowIndexOfInterest)
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(cell -> {
        // do whatever you need with the cell....
    });
```

Comment: Hi again :) Thanks for the "hacks".
I know now the location is used to create an animation between tables' cells(the illusion of values moving from one cell to another).
I still can't figure out another way to do it, but I thought you might, and if so, I'll use it gladly.

Comment: Fine,  Adding one thing, I have passed the column which I created on the stage first.  new column not worked.

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you! Btw, is there any way to filter a single column (which is done by c.getTableColumn() == columnOfInterest) but also filter selected rows?